# Energy values in case of 1D infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, potential, schroedinger-equation, ground-state

[image]

As it is depicted in the picture, there are 4 types of potential wells and if $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4$ represent the ground state energies of the particle confined in those wells, what should be the correct order of energies $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4$?

How to find the ordering without doing much of mathematics? Is there any logical argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would say it depends on the values of $V_0$ and $a$.

But we can try to formulate some logical argument, starting from Heisenberg's uncertainty relation $\Delta p \cdot \Delta x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$ and the energy formula $E = \frac{\hbar^2 p^2}{2m}$.

For the potential with infinite walls in a) we know that the boundary conditions require that the wave function vanishes exactly at the boundary. So, there is not even a little part of the wave function in the region outside $[0,a]$. Contrarily, for b) the wave function will have non-zero amplitude for $x > a$, hence $\Delta x_b > \Delta x_a$. By the same argument, we can argue that in d) the wave function can also enter $x < 0$. Therefore, $\Delta x_d > \Delta x_b > \Delta x_a$.

Therefore, we can (handwavingly) argue that since the uncertainty relation still has to hold, $\Delta p_a > \Delta p_b > \Delta p_d$, hence $E_a > E_b > E_d$.

For setting c) it's getting a bit more tricky. The wave functions for a linear potential are Airy functions, therefore the solution in the middle region looks clearly different than for all the three other cases. I am not sure how that effects the ground state energy.
I would finish my argument by observing that (compared to b) the linear potential constrains $\Delta x$ more than in b), therefore $\Delta x_c < \Delta x_b$, hence $E_c > E_b$, but I am not sure how to relate $\Delta x_a$ and $\Delta x_c$.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this question was asked in one of PhD interviews and they were expecting an analytical argumentative answer. For the case-3, is there any way to determine the ground state energy of the particle? This was all the information that was provided and it was stated that in each case, the particle is confined in those wells.

Comment: For the linear potential it is a bit tricky, since the corresponding eigenfunctions are Airy functions. If there was only a linear potential (for$x\in[0,\infty)$ and $0$ for $x<0$) the energy eigenstates would be given by the roots of the AiryAi function (highly non-linear function!). I remember that once I compared the eigenstates of this setting with those of the "box with infinite walls" but, obviously, the result depended on the choice of $a$ and the slope of the linear potential. So, I am pretty sure that you were not expected to do the calculations by hand at the interview.

Comment: I suppose with the argumentation from my answer, would have been satisfying for the interview for a), b) and d). And I am also quite sure that $E_c > E_b$ is correct. In an interview, they definitely cannot expect more maths than this. So, the only remaining question is whether $E_a$ is greater or smaller than $E_c$. Maybe c) was only given to see how you deal with non-unambigous questions? At least I would expect that you can find choices of $a$ and $V_0$ that produce $E_a > E_c$ and others that give the opposite...

Comment: Now I got your point.